# Conditional sum of range with blank cells in Calc

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have the following data in a spreadsheet:

```
----------------------
|Event |Value1|Value2|
|AAA   |1     |1     |
|BBB   |1     |3     |
|BBB   |      |2     |
|AAA   |3     |      |
----------------------
```

I wish to calculate the sum of all numbers in `Value1` and `Value2`, so I have an output of:

```
--------------
|Type  |Total|
|AAA   |5    |
|BBB   |6    |
--------------
```

To do this, I need a formula in the cells under `Total`. However, the formulas I've tried do not work when blank cells exist. If I were to put a 0 in every blank cell, I would get the desired outcome, but my data set is much larger than the provided example, and having that many cells with 0 would reduce readability.

The formula I've tried is shown below. Assume `Event` is A1, and `Type` is A10.

```
=SUMIFS(B2:C5,A2:A5,A11)
```

Now, if every blank cell contained a zero, the output shown above would be what I'd see with this formula. The formula sums up every value in the B2:C5 range if `Event` values from A2:A5 match A11, which is the string AAA, to output a total of 5.

So the question is, how can I ignore blank cells, without putting a 0 in them? I've thought about using `N()` or `ISBLANK()`, but neither of those work on ranges. Only individual cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear in what `Calc` version `=SUMIFS(B2:C5,A2:A5,A11)` will work at all even if all values in `B2:C5` are numeric. As per definition the sum range and the criteria ranges must be of same size. But here they are not of same size.

But

[image]

Formula in `B11`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$5=$A11)*ISNUMBER($B$2:$C$5),($B$2:$C$5))
```

should work and also should be most compatible with all spreadsheet applications.

How it works:

`($A$2:$A$5=$A11)` gets a 1 column x 4 rows matrix of `{TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE}` of whether the value in `$A$2:$A$5` equals `$A11`.  This multiplied by with `ISNUMBER($B$2:$C$5)`, which is a 2 columns x 4 rows matrix of `{TRUE,TRUE;TRUE,TRUE;FALSE,TRUE;TRUE,FALSE}` of whether the value in `$B$2:$C$5` is numeric, gets a 2 columns x 4 rows matrix of `{1,1;0,0;0,0;1,0}` of whether the value in `$A$2:$A$5` equals `$A11` AND the value in `$B$2:$C$5` is numeric. Then `SUMPRODUCT` makes a sum product of this both arrays `{1,1;0,0;0,0;1,0}` and `$B$2:$C$5` = `1*B2 + 1*C2 + 0*B3 + 0*C3 + 0*B4 + 0*D4 + 1*B5 + 0*C5`.

Comment: Odd. I should be getting 45 and 3.9 on my real spreadsheet, and instead I'm getting 24 and 0. Does it make a difference if some cells are on different sheets? I'm using `=SUMPRODUCT(($'OtherSheet'.$B$2:$B$32=$A3)*ISNUMBER($'OtherSheet'.$K$2:$V$32),($'OtherSheet'.$K$2:$V$32))`, where `$A3` is on the same sheet as the formula. This is to obtain the 45 that's somehow a 24. The second set of numbers uses the same formula in the next cell, with `$A4` instead.

Comment: @hiigaran: Cannot reproduce. Works for me in different sheets also. Are you sure there are exact matches for `$'OtherSheet'.$B$2:$B$32=$A3` as you suspect? Maybe there are "AAA" vs. "AAA " or vs  " AAA"  - leading or trailing spaces?

Comment: Okay, that was an embarrassing solution. Turns out I completely forgot that my range continued for many more rows down the sheet.